# How to import module cartopy

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Jupyter and Cartopy on a virtual environment. Once I have activated it and go to Jupyter Notebook and try to import it, I get an error that says that there is no module named "Cartopy". I have checked the list of modules installed and Cartopy appears on it. However, I can't import it.

I have checked that the environment is activated and I also tried uninstalling Jupyter from the base but it took so long (stuck on solving environment) so I quitted.

Comment: Tryi running in a new cell in  notebook running in the environment in which you want to work with cartopy, `%conda install -c conda-forge cartopy`. Let it complete the installation process even if solving takes quite a while. (This is assuming you are using conda since you mentioned 'solving'. That you are or are not using Anaconda/conda should have actually been clearly spelled out in the post along with the exact steps you used to install, what you tried to do to import, the error message, etc..) Restart the kernel and then try the appropriate import statement for cartopy.